# How to find the average speed of the car from this curve.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: ?]

I think I have to find first average speed of every hour. Then I have to find the average of them.

Am I correct? If I am correct  , then can you please tell me how to find average speed in a interval of one hour?

If I am wrong  then please give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Average speed, by definition, is total distance travelled divided by total time taken.

The total distance is the area under the speed-time curve. Since your curve seems to be composed of straight line segments, the trapezium rule will give an exact value. Of course, the more elementary approach of dividing up the area into smaller polygonal segments that you can easily work out the area of summing them up will work fine as well.

Note that your proposed method of averaging out the hourly speed will give you the wrong result in general.

Anyway, here's the solution using the trapezium rule:

Total distance travelled = $\frac 12((0+0) + 2(10+10+30+40+30+30)) = 150 \ \mathrm{km}$

Total time taken = $7 \ \mathrm{h}$.

Average speed = $\frac{150 \  \mathrm{km}}{7 \ \mathrm{h}} \approx 21.43 \ \mathrm{km/h}$

A brief note on why Yves' approach works for *this* case: it can be shown (quite easily) that in a state of constant acceleration (which means a linear increase or decrease in speed), the distance $s$ travelled is given by $s = \frac{(u+v)t}{2}$, where $u,v$ represent the initial and final speeds respectively and $t$ the time elapsed. Your graph can be subdivided into segments with constant acceleration, each exactly $1$ hour in duration, so the distance formula above reduces to $s = \frac 12 (u+v)$, which is also the simple average of the initial and final speeds of that interval. So what's happening here is that adding up all these average speeds gives the same result as adding up the distances travelled in these intervals, which is the same as the total distance travelled. And dividing by $7$ is the same as dividing by the total time taken.

The method will fail, if you have unequal time intervals which you fail to account for. For example, if you have a graph that goes from $0$ to $10$ (simple average $5$) in the first hour, then from $10$ to $30$ (simple average $20$) in the next $5$ hours, the average speed should be $\frac{105}{6} = 17.5$, but if you naively tried to average $5$ and $20$, you'd obviously get the wrong answer of $12.5$. However, if you had taken the *time-weighted* average of the averages, i.e. $\frac{(1)(5) + (5)(20)}{1+5}$, that would give the correct answer. So Yves' approach will work with any speed-time curve composed entirely of straight-line segments provided you are careful about ensuring the time intervals are equal (or take the time-weighted average).

I still feel it's better to keep things simple and proceed with the proper definition. You can't go wrong this way.

Comment: You should explain your "in general". For the given problem, it works quite well.

Comment: In the 3rd last line , why you have multiplied with 3?@Deepak

Comment: @cmi Which line is that?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was more interested in giving the proper general method, but let me think of a little edit to explain why your shortcut works in this case.

Comment: third line from the last@Deepak

Comment: @cmi Please quote the line you're referring to. I see no multiplication by $3$, and I've edited since (but not altered what I'd written previously).

Comment: sorry sorry it's 2 not 3... Why have you multiplied with 2?@Deepak

Comment: "Total distance travelled = $\frac 12((0+0) + 2(10+10+30+40+30+30)) = 150 \ \mathrm{km}$  " -- i AM TALKING ABOUT THIS LINE..

Comment: @cmi That's essentially the Trapezium Rule, a way to approximate the areas under curves (which is also called numerical integration). Where the curve comprises straight line segments like in this case, you can get an exact answer. You can look up the method and formula here: https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/pure-maths/calculus/trapezium-rule

Comment: You can remember the rule as "half the interval width times (whole sum of (first and last ordinates) plus (twice sum of intervening ordinates))".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and this approach is virtually the same as that of Deepak.

The averages are $$5,10,20,35, 35,30,15$$ and the average of averages

$$\frac{150}7=21.42857\cdots$$

Beware that the average of averages only works if all "slices" have the same width, otherwise you give more weight to the larger ones.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that the question is not well posed!  It should be asking "what is the average speed of the car over the entire trip?".  No, you do not "find average speed of every hour. Then find the average of them." There is nothing special about "one hour" as a unit of time.

First, it is important that this asks for "average *speed*". not "average *velocity*"!  I started to say that, since the starting point was the same as the end point, you went a *net* 0 miles so your average **velocity** is 0 miles per hour (If you go 40 miles in one direction and 40 miles in the opposite direction, your net motion is 40+ (-40)= 0).

But you asked about average "speed" so that direction is not important.  You went 40 miles in one direction and the 40 miles in the opposite direction so you went a total of 40+ 40= 80 miles in 7 hour so you average speed was 80/7= 11.43 miles per hour (rounded to two decimal places).

Comment: The vertical axis is speed.

Comment: But the answer is 11.43.. You must have misunderstood something..